# "RuntimeError: no running event loop" with "asyncio.get_running_loop()" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm trying to run the code below with [**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop):

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() # Here

loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

But, I got the error below:

> RuntimeError: no running event loop

I could run the code above by replacing [**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop) with [**asyncio.get_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) as shown below but [**asyncio.get_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) is **deprecated since version 3.10** so I don't want to use it.

```py
# ...

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Here
# loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

# ...
```

So, this is the result below:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

So, how can I run the code above with [**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop)?

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** tried to get a running event loop but there is no running event loop to get:

[**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop):

> Return the running event loop in the current OS thread.
>
> If there is no running event loop a RuntimeError is raised. This
> function can only be called from a coroutine or a callback.

So, you need to create and set an event loop with [**asyncio.new_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.new_event_loop) and [**asyncio.set_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.set_event_loop) instead of using **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() # Here
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) # Here

# loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

Then, your code works properly:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

In addition, you can use **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** like below. In this case, there is a running event loop and **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** gets it so the error doesn't occur:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def call_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() # Here
    await loop.create_task(test())

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(call_test())
```

Then, this code works properly as well:

```
Test
Test
Test
```